# I am getting an error when I try to write a pandas dataframe back to my SQL database

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to read the Orders table from the Northwind database and then write it back to the database under a new table name called 'Orders_New'. I have the following Python code:

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=DESKTOP-A1DUCDS\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=Northwind;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from Orders', cnxn)

print(df)

df.to_sql('Orders_New',con=cnxn,index=False)
```

However, when I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), the second parameter of `DataFrame.to_sql()` is expected to be *sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection) or sqlite3.Connection*

> **con sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection) or sqlite3.Connection**
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects.
> The user is responsible for engine disposal and connection closure for
> the SQLAlchemy connectable See [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html).